# How to handle PyObjC method that returns NSError?

Tags: python, objective-c, cocoa, avaudiorecorder, pyobjc

I am trying to get my PyObjC app to record audio when the user clicks a button. I am attempting to use the [AVAuidioRecorder](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioRecorder_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html) class. My code is:

```
@IBAction
def startRecording_(self, sender):

    audioPath = '~/Desktop/recordTest.mp3'
    audioPathStr = NSString.stringByExpandingTildeInPath(audioPath)
    audioURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath_(audioPathStr)

    audioSettings = {'AVFormatIDKey': 'kAudioFormatAppleIMA4', 'AVSampleRateKey': 1600.0, 'AVNumberOfChannelsKey': 1 }
    audioDict = NSDictionary.dictionaryWithDictionary_(audioSettings)

    (recorder, error) = AVAudioRecorder.alloc().initWithURL_settings_error_(audioURL, audioDict, objc.nil)
    recorder.record()
```

When I run the above code, I get the following error:

```
<type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

It seems that the `initWithURL_settings_error_` method is expecting an iterable object as its third parameter. However, I thought when I use a PyObjC method that calls for an error parameter, I can pass `objc.nil` or `None` to that parameter.

When I use a similar syntax on an [NSString](https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) method:

```
(names, error) = NSString.stringWithContentsOfFile_encoding_error_(u"/usr/share/dict/propernames", NSASCIIStringEncoding, objc.nil)
```

the code runs.

Why does my call to the AVAudioRecord method not work? Is it because the method calls for an *outError* while the NSString method calls for an *error*?

Comment: Semantically, you should use `None` or `objc.NULL` for that argument, but `objc.nil` should work. I don't believe that is the source of that exception. Are you sure that the URL you've created is not `None`, and that the file exists at that path? Also, note that you don't have to convert a Python dict into an `NSDictionary` like this; you can pass the dict in as the argument, and the bridge will handle it for you.

Comment: @JoshCaswell The URL is not `None` and I don't think the file should exist at that path yet since this AVAudioRecorder should create that file, not read it.

Answer (score 3):

The code doesn't work with this AVFoundation class because PyObjC does not have metadata descriptions for that framework. It therefore does know what kind of argument the last argument is, it only knows that it is pointer to an object but doesn't know that it is used as a pass-by-reference output argument.

To manually inspect what PyObjC knows about this argument::

```
>> import AVFoundation
>>> AVFoundation.AVAudioRecorder.initWithURL_settings_error_.__metadata__( ['arguments'][-1]
{'null_accepted': True, 'already_retained': False, 'type': '^@', 'already_cfretained': False}
```

The type should have been "o^@" here.

This is with Apple's build of PyObjC: you can use "import AVFoundation" with that build, and that will use the BridgeSupport data files inside the AVFoundation framework. Sadly enough that data is incomplete and doesn't have information on this method and that's why the type is wrong here.

It is fairly easy to fix this for this particular method by using PyObjCs metadata API:

```
import objc
objc.registerMetaDataForSelector(b"AVAudioRecorder", b"initWithURL:settings:error:",
        dict(
            arguments={
               4: dict(type_modifier=objc._C_OUT),
            }
        ))
```

Fixing the metadata for all of AVFoundation will be more work :-(

Comment: how do you import `AVFoundation` it is not in `pyobjc`